# How to install Proj4js.js in my localhost directory?

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers-2

I'm developing a GIS website for vineyard management. I am using Openlayers with the WMTS IGN (French institute for geography) datas. It works fine.

I also would like to add the possibility for the user to switch to a geology map provided by the BRGM (geological french institute) geoservice.

The issue is that IGN datas avec in Webmercator projection (EPSG:3857) and BRGM datas avec in EPSG:27572 (NTF (Paris)) and i would like to keep map center and bounds while switching from one to the other one. After reading a lot on the internet, i found i needed to use Proj4js for projection transformation. I also have vestor shapes (vineyard fields) and i would need to visualize in both projections by transforming them.

I am quite used to implement js librairies (by copying js files in my localhost and include it in the header of my php/html file) but in the case of proj4js, it looks different. The gituhub page only gives this information for installation :

```
npm install proj4
bower install proj4
jam install proj4
component install proj4js/proj4js
```

I have no idea how it works and i can't get any clear information from what i read. In the github files, there is no proj4js.js file... Is there somewhere a clear tutorial for installation ? Does someone have experience on this installation ?

I tried a "classical" installation downloading 1.1.0 from this link http://download.osgeo.org/proj4js/proj4js-1.1.0.zip but it seems to be an old version and i'm getting errors with the test code below : 
    "lcc:forward: llInputOutOfRange: NaN : NaN"

Here is my test code :

```
<head>

<script src="js/proj4js/lib/proj4js-compressed.js"></script>
<script src="js/proj4js/lib/defs/EPSG3857.js"></script>
<script src="js/proj4js/lib/defs/EPSG27572.js"></script>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/2.13.1/OpenLayers.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">


var source = new Proj4js.Proj("EPSG:3857");
var dest = new Proj4js.Proj("EPSG:27572");

Proj4js.reportError = function (msg) {
    throw new Error('Whoops: ' + msg);
};

var position1 = new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 5700000);

    console.log(source);
    console.log(dest);
    console.log(position1);

    console.log(Proj4js.transform(source, dest, position1));


</script>


</body>
```

Comment: you should use: `var transformed=position1.transform(source, dest);`